# Collecting information from API callback with Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, bots

I am trying to get a [Groupme](http://groupme.com) (groupme is a group chat app) bot to work using Google Apps Script but I am having trouble figuring out what I'm missing in order to collect the JSON data from the callback.

I went through the [Groupme Bot Documentation](https://dev.groupme.com/tutorials/bots) set up my bot properly and my bot can post to the group but I can't pull data from messages that people post.

Here is my code:

```
function doGet(groupMeData) {
  var incoming = JSON.parse(groupMeData)

  if(incoming.text == "bot"){
    var url = 'https://api.groupme.com/v3/bots/post'
    var payload = {
      "bot_id" : "abc123_Bot_ID",
      "text" : "hello_world " + incoming.id
    }
    var options = {
      "method" : "post",
      "payload" : payload
    }
UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,options);
Logger.log(incoming);
  };
};
```

I can post to the groupme group when I run the function but can't get it working where if anyone posts a message with 'bot' then it responds with 'hello_world' and that users ID. I've read about `ContentService` in Google Apps Script and feel like it should be involved but don't know where it fits in.

The response would look like this:

```
{
  "attachments": [],
  "avatar_url": "http://i.groupme.com/123456789",
  "created_at": 1302623328,
  "group_id": "1234567890",
  "id": "1234567890",
  "name": "John",
  "sender_id": "12345",
  "sender_type": "user",
  "source_guid": "GUID",
  "system": false,
  "text": "Hello world ☃☃",
  "user_id": "1234567890"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What does your client side code look like? Are you doing something like this:

```
// code to collect data from user, maybe JQuery
function getJSON() {
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(clientCallBack)
    .withFailureHandler(clientFailureFunction)
    .doGet(groupMeData);
}

function clientCallBack(content) {
  // do something with response
}

function clientFailureFunction() {
  // report error
}
```

On the server side, you probably do need to use Content Service. Try wrapping your JSON up in a [TextOutput](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/content/text-output#) object:

```
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
var content = ContentService.createTextOutput(response)
  .setMimeType("JSON");
return content;
```

If that doesn't work, post more details of what you're trying to do. Google Apps Script documentation requires a rabbinical level of interpretive skill sometimes.